# Sony Vaio keyboard not working

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, keyboard, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio laptop model number VGN-AR88E which belongs to my local church. A few months ago I upgraded the laptop from windows vista to windows 10 and every thing was working fine.

However I recently brought it home to update it again and after the updates were complete the keyboard did not work. Suspecting a driver issue I went into the device manager and everything seemed fine as it said the latest driver was installed and that the device was working properly.

I then went to the Sony support website to see if they could provide me with new driver that I could install there were none.

So I went back to the device manager and I noticed that there were 2 devices with issues one was a mass storage controller and the other just said unknown and in the properties there was no helpful information that I could see that could help me identify it.

However after a lot of research and running several driver update scans (I did not download or install anything as a result of the scans) I identified it as the Sony firmware extension parser so I went to the Sony website and downloaded the latest driver available for my model and installed it after I installed the driver I rebooted the laptop to see if it had fixed my problem but it hadn’t.

I am nearly at my wits end about what to do and the church cannot afford a new laptop.

Comment: First off, worse case, buy an external keyboard! I know not ideal but for $5 it may be an OK work around. Did you try roll back the most recent updates? Going to manufacturer and updating driver is usually the best thing but do make sure the chipset driver is up to date

Comment: Is your On-Screen Keyboard Working?? If yes then there is problem in your keyboard not in your system.

Comment: @Dave thanks for your suggestion yes I have tried rolling back the updates but that does not work I have also checked multiple times using multiple utilities (to try and find out what the unknown device that turned out to be the firmware extension parser)  and all the drivers are up to date

Comment: @selah1936 to answer your question yes the on-screen keyboard is working however i was able to verify that the physical keyboard worked by booting the computer into an Ubuntu live CD where the physical keyboard worked fine. so it is actually a problem with windows not the keyboard.

Comment: There is a similar post I've seen, although it was for VM. sadly they had to reinstall the OS

Comment: @Dave are there any other forums that you would recommend I post on to see if anyone their has a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is complicated and you're research/attempts to fix it have sadly not provided the solution.

For me, there are only 3 solutions left.

1. Send it to some one (an IT professional)
2. Use an external keyboard
3. Since rollback failed, reinstall the OS

Comment: i have reinstalled the os which seems to have worked